# Space text boxes after their label

Tags: html, css

With style sheets I float `name`, `email` left and `nickname` and `school` right but I would like their text boxes to start at the same point. How can I achieve this with CSS?

```html
<div id="container" align="center">
  <div id="name">Name:
    <input id="name_text" type="text">
  </div>
  <div id="nickname">Nickname:
    <input id="nickname_text" type="text">
  </div>
  <div id="email">Email Address:
    <input id="email_text" type="text">
  </div>
  <div id="school">School:
    <input id="school_text" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that necessary for using this much div tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-style: oblique;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" align="center">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>Name:</p>
      <input type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Nickname:</p>
      <input type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Email Address:</p>
      <input type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>School:</p>
      <input type="text">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Smoggs/pen/MwNwaG)

Comment: Do you really need a paragraph tag for that?

Comment: Beautiful! now since i wasn't familiar with strong tags, is there anyway to style them as different font because overtime i attempt it just ends up being bolder

Comment: @AlexGannon I've just edited my answer (see CSS section) to show how to style text, see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp for ideas on styling as you desire

Comment: I know briefly how to style font. I based by code using strong tags so the text and the text boxes would be lined up. But i can't style strong tags?

Comment: @AlexGannon ah I see, you can still style <strong> tags, for example if you occasionally want text not to be so bold you can do this with css: strong { 
    font-weight: normal;
} which removes the bold effect from a <strong> tag

Comment: @AlexGannon if could upvote my answer that would be appreciated, also ticking the best answer will mark the questioned as answered/resolved (personally I'd say Praveen's answer was best)

Answer (score 4):

**You have to use this way:**

1. There should be `<label>` to make sure when the user clicks on the label text, it focuses on the respective input.
2. The `<strong>` tag has a `display: inline-block` making it easy to set the width.
3. You don't need so many `id`s.
4. You need to give `name` attribute to all the `<input />` fields.

```css
label strong {display: inline-block; width: 150px; text-align: left; margin: 0 0 10px;}
```

```html
<div id="container" align="center">
  <div id="name">
    <label>
      <strong>Name:</strong>
      <input id="name_text" type="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="nickname">
    <label>
      <strong>Nickname:</strong>
      <input id="nickname_text" type="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="email">
    <label>
      <strong>Email Address:</strong>
      <input id="email_text" type="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="school">
    <label>
      <strong>School:</strong>
      <input id="school_text" type="text" />
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not know you could put the input element inside the <label>, so you don't have to use the for attribute. Thanks for the information!

Comment: @Emil Yes, that's the way to do. But this doesn't work for tabular layout, where the label and input will be in different areas.

Answer (score 0):

A little modification,copy this code and check it.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    label strong {display: inline-block; width: 150px; text-align: left; margin: 0 0 10px;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <div id="Holder" style="width:50%;">
            <div id="L_div" style="float:left;">
                <div id="container" align="center">
                  <div id="name">
                    <label>
                      <strong>Name:</strong>
                      <input id="name_text" type="text" />
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div id="email">
                    <label>
                      <strong>Email Address:</strong>
                      <input id="email_text" type="text" />
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
              <div id="R_div" style="float:right;">
                  <div id="nickname">
                    <label>
                      <strong>Nickname:</strong>
                      <input id="nickname_text" type="text" />
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div id="school">
                    <label>
                      <strong>School:</strong>
                      <input id="school_text" type="text" />
                    </label>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If you are a fresher in css use this site [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/css) for guidence

Regds

Comment: Thank you so much, you definitely cleaned up my code and taught me some things. As far as editing everything for a smaller screen width, how would i align everything vertically in one column?